# removing spaces and cleaning table in latex

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, formatting

[image]
how to remove the spaces which i think from automatic justification in table

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|m{33.19mm}|m{43.51mm}|m{39.54mm}|m{10.96mm}|m{9.11mm}|}
\caption{Main entries in data extraction form}\\
\hline
Title &
Methodology &
Conclusion &
Q ID &
Key\\\hline
Carving contiguous fragmented files with fast object validation \cite{Garfinkel2007c}
&
Developing algorithm that validate carved data 
for JPEG and Microsoft documents & Internal File Structure is very important in the process of carving data and the process of validating results &
Q1
 &
K0
\newline
K8
\newline
K9
\\\hline
Reconstructing corrupt DEFLATED Files \cite{Brown2011} &
Bit-stream pattern search and try /error &
Recovering data from corrupted archive file by examining the file structure and trying to reconstruct lost or damaged parts  &
Q2
 &
K9
\\\hline
Forensic Data Carving \cite{Povar2011a} &
Multiple Methods for contiguous data carving based on file header/footer and also file structure, with validation proposal &
Discussed different methods for file carving and representing results related to these methods and limitations &
Q1
\newline
Q2
 &
K2
\newline
K3
\newline
K8
\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try using `\raggedright`.  The problem is that making narrow columns flush usually results in wide interword gaps.

Comment: or `\RaggedRight`  (from package `ragged2e`) if you want to allow some hyphenation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I use `\raggedright` in the first 3 columns to eliminate the excess interword space that comes from flush alignment.

To apply it to a whole column, I use the specification

```
\begin{longtable}{|>{\raggedright}m{33.19mm}|>{\raggedright}m{43.51mm}|
  >{\raggedright}m{39.54mm}|m{10.96mm}|m{9.11mm}|}
```

which adds the macro `\raggedright` as the first item in each cell entry for those columns.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\raggedright}m{33.19mm}|>{\raggedright}m{43.51mm}|
  >{\raggedright}m{39.54mm}|m{10.96mm}|m{9.11mm}|}
\caption{Main entries in data extraction form}\\
\hline
Title &
Methodology &
Conclusion &
Q ID &
Key\\\hline
Carving contiguous fragmented files with fast object validation \cite{Garfinkel2007c}
&
Developing algorithm that validate carved data 
for JPEG and Microsoft documents & Internal File Structure is very important in the process of carving data and the process of validating results &
Q1
 &
K0
\newline
K8
\newline
K9
\\\hline
Reconstructing corrupt DEFLATED Files \cite{Brown2011} &
Bit-stream pattern search and try /error &
Recovering data from corrupted archive file by examining the file structure and trying to reconstruct lost or damaged parts  &
Q2
 &
K9
\\\hline
Forensic Data Carving \cite{Povar2011a} &
Multiple Methods for contiguous data carving based on file header/footer and also file structure, with validation proposal &
Discussed different methods for file carving and representing results related to these methods and limitations &
Q1
\newline
Q2
 &
K2
\newline
K3
\newline
K8
\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one takes Bernard's suggestion to use the `ragged2e` package, hyphenation can also be achieved:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\RaggedRight}m{33.19mm}|>{\RaggedRight}m{43.51mm}|
  >{\RaggedRight}m{39.54mm}|m{10.96mm}|m{9.11mm}|}
\caption{Main entries in data extraction form}\\
\hline
Title &
Methodology &
Conclusion &
Q ID &
Key\\\hline
Carving contiguous fragmented files with fast object validation \cite{Garfinkel2007c}
&
Developing algorithm that validate carved data 
for JPEG and Microsoft documents & Internal File Structure is very important in the process of carving data and the process of validating results &
Q1
 &
K0
\newline
K8
\newline
K9
\\\hline
Reconstructing corrupt DEFLATED Files \cite{Brown2011} &
Bit-stream pattern search and try /error &
Recovering data from corrupted archive file by examining the file structure and trying to reconstruct lost or damaged parts  &
Q2
 &
K9
\\\hline
Forensic Data Carving \cite{Povar2011a} &
Multiple Methods for contiguous data carving based on file header/footer and also file structure, with validation proposal &
Discussed different methods for file carving and representing results related to these methods and limitations &
Q1
\newline
Q2
 &
K2
\newline
K3
\newline
K8
\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I propose to improve the table using `ltablex`, which extends `longtable` to `tabularx` environments. Also, I don't use  any vertical rules, and replace most horizontal rules with vertical spacing, with the `booktabs` package. The last two columns are simple `c` columns – the `makecell` package allows for line breaks in such cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} \usepackage{array, makecell, booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

 \begin{document}

\vspace*{8cm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{3}{X}cc}
  \caption{Main entries in data extraction form}\\
  \toprule
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize\tablename~\thetable (continued)}\\
  \toprule
  \endhead
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize To be continued}
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot
  %%%
  Title & Methodology & Conclusion & Q ID & Key \\%
  \midrule
  Carving contiguous fragmented files with fast object validation \cite{Garfinkel2007c}
  & Developing algorithm that validate carved data for JPEG and Microsoft documents %
  & Internal File Structure is very important in the process of carving data and the process of validating results%
  & Q1 & \makecell{K0\\K8\\K9} \\%
  \addlinespace
  Reconstructing corrupt DEFLATED Files \cite{Brown2011} & Bit-stream pattern search and try /error %
  & Recovering data from corrupted archive file by examining the file structure and trying to reconstruct lost or damaged parts %
  & Q2 & K9 \\%
  \addlinespace
  Forensic Data Carving \cite{Povar2011a} %
  & Multiple Methods for contiguous data carving based on file header/footer and also file structure, with validation proposal %
  & Discussed different methods for file carving and representing results related to these methods and limitations %
  & \makecell{Q1\\Q2} & \makecell{K2\\K3\\K8}%
  %Title & Methodology & Conclusion & Q ID & Key \\%
  %\midrule
  \\Carving contiguous fragmented files with fast object validation \cite{Garfinkel2007c}
  & Developing algorithm that validate carved data for JPEG and Microsoft documents %
  & Internal File Structure is very important in the process of carving data and the process of validating results%
  & Q1 & \makecell{K0\\K8\\K9} \\%
  \addlinespace
  Reconstructing corrupt DEFLATED Files \cite{Brown2011} & Bit-stream pattern search and try /error %
  & Recovering data from corrupted archive file by examining the file structure and trying to reconstruct lost or damaged parts %
  & Q2 & K9 \\%
  \addlinespace
  Forensic Data Carving \cite{Povar2011a} %
  & Multiple Methods for contiguous data carving based on file header/footer and also file structure, with validation proposal %
  & Discussed different methods for file carving and representing results related to these methods and limitations %
  & \makecell{Q1\\Q2} & \makecell{K2\\K3\\K8} %
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Let me know if you wish me to edit out of my answer the incorporation of your comment, since you choose to answer as well. +1 in any event.

Comment: You don't have to. The main difference between your answer and mine is using `tabularx` and `booktabs`, that's why I posted.