# problem in using a 'p' type column to control automatic line-break in tabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I want the text in tabular to be automatically line-break, and I use a 'p' type column to realize.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.7cm}|p{2.7cm}|p{2.5cm}}
 \hline
 \cline{1-6}
Genitourinary   & Grade 1 & Grade 2   & Grade 3   & Grade 4  \\
\hline
Dysurie          & Not therapy       & Oral treatment (no narcotic analgesics)    & Narcotic analgesics   & Not \defined \\
Frequency      & once/2h, twice pretherapy        & once/1h     &once/0.5h (more frequent than hourly)  & Not defined  \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill \break
\end{document}
```

But the output is not exactly what I want since there are a large space (mark as red line in the picture) between two words. Could somebody have idea to fix it? Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Add `\raggedright` to cells.  If you are using `tabularx` for example, you can do it for a whoie column with `>{\raggedright}p{...}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes No, it does not work. I add it after `&` , and the content in one cell will jump to other cell.

Comment: I am sorry for not explaining, `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}|>{\raggedright}p{2.5cm}|>{\raggedright}p{2.7cm}|>{\raggedright}p{2.7cm}|p{2.5cm}}
 \hline
 \cline{1-5}
Genitourinary   & Grade 1 & Grade 2   & Grade 3   & Grade 4  \\
\hline
Dysurie          & Not therapy       & Oral treatment (no narcotic analgesics)    & Narcotic analgesics   & Not defined \\
Frequency      & once/2h, twice pretherapy        & once/1h     &once/0.5h (more frequent than hourly)  & Not defined  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}`

Comment: Alternately, without `tabularx`, like this: `Dysurie          & Not therapy       & \raggedright Oral treatment (no narcotic analgesics)    & \raggedright  Narcotic analgesics   & Not defined `

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305524/removing-spaces-and-cleaning-table-in-latex as a possible duplicate?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to allow hyphenation while having a normal spacing between words, you can use the `\RaggedRight` directive at the beginning of each column.

Also, since your table is almost textwidth large, why not use `tabularx`? You won't have to calculate how wide each column has to be in order to fit `text width`.

Last remark: since `\hline\cline` only makes a thicker rule, you can as well load `makecell` and uses its `\Xhline` command for lines of variable width. You then can also use the `\makecell` command to have centred column heads.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}%

\begin{document}

\centering \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.5cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.7cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.7cm}|p{2.5cm}}
 \hline
 \cline{1-5}
Genitourinary & Grade 1 & Grade 2 & Grade 3 & Grade 4 \\
\hline
Dysurie & Not therapy & Oral treatment (no narcotic analgesics) & Narcotic analgesics & Not defined \\
Frequency & once/2h, twice pretherapy & once/1h &once/0.5h (more frequent than hourly) & Not defined \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X*{4}{|>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}}
   \Xhline{0.8pt}
Genitourinary & \makecell{Grade 1} & \makecell{Grade 2} & \makecell{Grade 3} & \makecell{Grade 4} \\
\hline
Dysurie & Not therapy & Oral treatment (no narcotic analgesics) & Narcotic analge\-sics & Not defined \\
Frequency & once/2h, twice pretherapy & once/1h &once/0.5h (more frequent than hourly) & Not defined \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\hfill \break

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But I am still confused about this syntex`{\linewidth}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X*{4}{|>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}`. Could you add some explanation about these parts`{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X*{4}`  and `{|>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}`, as well as `|>`. I found it quite hard to make it clear by myself.

Comment: The syntax `>{some commands}X` makes the commands to be executed on entering the cell (it may be any type of cells). This syntax is defined in the `array` package (loaded here by `tabularx`). You should take a look at the documentation of `array`. `\arraybackslash`  makes latex know that in this context, `\\` means `\tabularnewline` and avoids problems at the end of rows. `{linewidth}` (the first argument of `tabularx`) says the overall width of the table will be `\linewidth`, and the environment will calculate the exact width of each `X` column.

Comment: Thank you, buty why not directly use `{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X*{5}`? Because the last part use the same syntax.

Comment: That's because you want no vertical rule at the left margin (nor at the right margin). Note the exact syntax I would use in this case would be `*{5}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}|X}`, so the first column would have a vertical rule on the left side.